# No answer from stripe webhook using ngrok

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks, payload, ngrok

I am using ngrok to test stripe webhooks on my rails 5.2 application, and there is no http request when a payment is completed on stripe. (the payment is successful though).

I set up the webhook like this:

## config/routes.rb

```
mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/stripe-webhooks'
```

## config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'checkout.session.completed', StripeCheckoutSessionService.new
end
```

## app/services/stripe_checkout_session_service.rb

```
class StripeCheckoutSessionService
  def call(event)
    order = Order.find_by(checkout_session_id: event.data.object.id)
    order.update(state: 'paid')
  end
end
```

What I see in my terminal when I process a payment, from ngrok:

```
Session Status                online                                                                                                                                          
Session Expires               7 hours, 45 minutes                                                                                                                             
Version                       2.3.35                                                                                                                                          
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                                              
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                                           
Forwarding                    http://a2544196cf1f.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000                                                                                           
Forwarding                    https://a2544196cf1f.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000                                                                                          

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                                     
                              10      0       0.00    0.00    20.80   61.31                                                                                                   

HTTP Requests                                                                                                                                                                 
-------------                                                                                                                                                                 

GET  /orders/2/messages/new                                                                                     200 OK                                                        
GET  /orders/2/payments/new                                                                                     200 OK                                                        
POST /orders/2                                                                                                  302 Found                                                     
GET  /assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-6a8c8e9e1e7f692c21af1956de163f3d026778e6449fe93a09a671847ca1ae65.woff2 200 OK                                                        
GET  /orders/2                                                                                                  200 OK                                                        
GET  /assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-7f4d3fd0a705dbf8403298aad91d5de6972e6b5d536068eba8b24954a5a0a8c7.woff2   200 OK                                                        
GET  /                                                                                                          200 OK                                                        
POST /users/sign_in                                                                                             302 Found                                                     
GET  /users/sign_in                                                                                             200 OK
```

I tried to send a webhook test from the stripe dashboard and I get a 400 error :

```
Cannot render console from 54.187.174.169! Allowed networks: 54.187.205.235, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1

Processing by StripeEvent::WebhookController#event as XML
  Parameters: {"created"=>1326853478, "livemode"=>false, "id"=>"evt_00000000000000", "type"=>"checkout.session.completed", "object"=>"event", "request"=>nil, "pending_webhooks"=>1, "api_version"=>nil, "data"=>{"object"=>{"id"=>"cs_00000000000000", "object"=>"checkout.session", "billing_address_collection"=>nil, "cancel_url"=>"https://example.com/cancel", "client_reference_id"=>nil, "customer"=>nil, "customer_email"=>nil, "livemode"=>false, "locale"=>nil, "metadata"=>{}, "mode"=>"payment", "payment_intent"=>"pi_00000000000000", "payment_method_types"=>["card"], "setup_intent"=>nil, "shipping"=>nil, "shipping_address_collection"=>nil, "submit_type"=>nil, "subscription"=>nil, "success_url"=>"https://example.com/success"}}, "webhook"=>{"created"=>1326853478, "livemode"=>false, "id"=>"evt_00000000000000", "type"=>"checkout.session.completed", "object"=>"event", "request"=>nil, "pending_webhooks"=>1, "api_version"=>nil, "data"=>{"object"=>{"id"=>"cs_00000000000000", "object"=>"checkout.session", "billing_address_collection"=>nil, "cancel_url"=>"https://example.com/cancel", "client_reference_id"=>nil, "customer"=>nil, "customer_email"=>nil, "livemode"=>false, "locale"=>nil, "metadata"=>{}, "mode"=>"payment", "payment_intent"=>"pi_00000000000000", "payment_method_types"=>["card"], "setup_intent"=>nil, "shipping"=>nil, "shipping_address_collection"=>nil, "submit_type"=>nil, "subscription"=>nil, "success_url"=>"https://example.com/success"}}}}

No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload
```

I tried to whitelist the ip in my development.rb file :

```
 config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '54.187.205.235'
```

But nothing happened. Any Help?

my orders controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end


  def update
    order = Order.find(params[:id])
    order.update(order_params)


    line_items_order = order.order_items.map { |item|{
      "name" => item.product.name,
      "amount" => item.product.price_cents,
      "currency" => 'eur',
      "quantity" => item.quantity,
      "description" => item.grind
      }
    }



    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      shipping_address_collection: {
        allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA', 'FR', 'PT', 'ES']
      },

      line_items: line_items_order,

      success_url: new_order_message_url(order),
      cancel_url: order_url(order)

    )

    order.update(checkout_session_id: session.id)
    redirect_to new_order_payment_path(order)

  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:amount_cents_cents)
  end

end
```

and I configured the stripe.rb file like this :

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  secret_key:      ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'],
  signing_secret:  ENV['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY']

  }

  Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
  StripeEvent.signing_secret = Rails.configuration.stripe[:signing_secret]

StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'checkout.session.completed', StripeCheckoutSessionService.new
end
```

with all the keys in the .env file

I finally got this response from stripe webhook dashboard :

```
<!doctype html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        strong { font-weight: bold; }
        hr { -moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; height: 0; }
        html { font-family: sans-serif;   -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;   } body { margin: 0; }
        a { background-color: transparent; }
        a:active, a:hover { outline: 0; }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
            .container { width: 500px; margin: auto; color: #444; padding: 5px; }
            a, strong { color: purple; text-decoration: none; }
            a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
            h2 { text-align: center; color: #000; }
            p { line-height: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">


<h2>Failed to complete tunnel connection</h2>
<hr />
<p>
    The connection to <strong><a href="http://a2544196cf1f.ngrok.io">http://a2544196cf1f.ngrok.io</a></strong>
    was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client,
    but the client failed to establish a connection to
    the local address <strong><a href="http://localhost:3000">localhost:3000</a></strong>.
</p>
<p>
    Make sure that a web service is running on
    <strong><a href="http://localhost:3000">localhost:3000</a></strong> and that it is a valid address.
</p>
<p>
    The error encountered was: <strong style="color: #9E2929">dial tcp [::1]:3000: connect: connection refused</strong>
</p>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I made the test from the ngrok http address, with my local host3000 running. Is that ok?

(when I run the test directly from the localhost 3000, I have a 502 error)

Thanks to  @taintedzodiac  I saw that my post request is wrong:

```
  "message": "You must pass either `subscription_data` or `line_items` or `mode`.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
```

I set the line_items in the Stripe::Checkout::Session.create, how could I pass thesame in the post?

Comment: Your application is receiving a webhook event from Stripe. What does your event handling code look like? It looks like signature verification did not work in your webhook handler code. Can you show what your code is doing? Make sure your webhook signing secret is added correctly there (don't paste the secret here, you can just double-check on your end)

Comment: Most commonly, the cause of a signature validation failure is due to middleware or something else that's modifying the request before it gets to your endpoint. I'd suggest checking that nothing is editing the body or headers (including the ordering) of the request before it gets to your endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my questions with my orders controller code and the rails configuration code for stripe signing key. I am not sure what to do to respond to "can you show what your code is doing?" I am new to rails, struggling ehe

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have a dedicated ngrok account, the domain name of the ngrok proxy will change if you terminate and restart ngrok on your local machine. To that end, I’m wondering if what you have works, but you haven’t POSTed the current callback url (ie Stripe has an invalid callback url to send the data to)?